# How to save date with time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

currently, i'm sending via a php script

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

to my mysql database

but the field is currently set to `DATE`, `binary` character set, display size and precision at `10` so it saves only the date, not the time, such as `2018-05-22`.

i want it to save `2018-05-22 15:10:10` — what do I need to change in my MySQL db for that field setting so that it saves the whole thing PHP is sending it?

Comment: change type to TIMESTAMP

Comment: Change type to `datetime`

Comment: Use the correct column type, i.e. DATETIME instead of just DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timestamp` in MySQL database and it will save the way you want.

Answer (score -2):

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

You can alter your table as:-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name DATETIME;
```

Reference:- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html